# Updating the tables and its records based upon the list of IDS in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

yesterday i had some help with gordon with q query but i need some more help with the code

I have the query below where

```
SELECT message, type, count(1) as total, 
       STUFF( (SELECT N',' + CONVERT(NVCHAR(MAX), id)
               FROM dbo.testing t2
               WHERE t2.message = t.message and t2.type = t.type
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
            )
FROM testing t
GROUP BY message,type 
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

i want to populate a field called eid starting from 1 to the number of records i have and each record have 1 or 5 or 10 ids which we just figured out lik: if the ids column have 5 ids like 18,19,20,21,22 for all these the eid will be 1

like this screenshot

http://prntscr.com/m4w5r5

i want to have the errorid first start from 1000 and for every row, it should increment but for every row, there are associated IDS which are in comma separated values, they all should have the same errorid for that row

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to allow somebody to help you easily, please, include DDL with existing data and expected results. Please have a look [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Bear in mind that just a few people will open any external link.

Comment: It is not at all clear what your are asking here. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is :

```
SELECT message
       ,type
       ,total
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY EID ORDER BY EID) AS EID
FROM ( 
SELECT message, type, count(1) as total, 
   EID = STUFF( (SELECT N',' + CONVERT(NVCHAR(MAX), id)
           FROM dbo.testing t2
           WHERE t2.message = t.message and t2.type = t.type
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
        )
FROM testing t
GROUP BY message,type 
HAVING count(1) > 1
)Res1
```